# exporting function from R package to cluster (parallel processing)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use parLapply again (now successfully used it in [this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169387/cannot-open-the-connection-error-with-parlapply)) but this time the function to parallelize contains some functions from the mc2d package (ie. deprt, ppert). I installed and loaded the package, before the parallel part of the code.

I successfully exported my variables to the cluster using cluster export,

```
clusterExport(C1, "variable")
...
```

However I tried to export the functions dpert and ppert using

```
clusterEvalQ(C1,dpert)
```

and I get the error

```
object C1 not found
```

how does it not find C1? is there another way to export R-packages functions to the cluster for parallel processing?

Answer (score 9):

Use clusterExport for functions as well...

```
clusterExport(Cl,c('dpert','variable'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I accidentally discovered is to add the name of the package to which the function belongs before the function call. E.g. instead of say `syms()` or `group_indices()` you use `rlang::syms()` or `dplyr::group_indices()` inside `parLapply()` (or any other `parallel` library function).

Comment: could you give a full `clusterExport` call example ?